# extensão xml no php faltando (debian)

Tags: php, xml, dom, extension

Estou tentando instalar as dependências do meu projeto com composer no **debian 11** e está dando erro que algumas estensões estão faltando. Porém eu já instalei a xml com o comando `sudo apt-install php7.4-xml` e se eu tento instalar novamente aparece que já está na versão mais atual. E também já reiniciei o apache após a instalação da extensão.

O que é que está faltando?

O erro que está aparecendo é:

```
Problem 1
    - phpoffice/phpexcel is locked to version 1.8.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.2 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xmlwriter extension.
  Problem 2
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles is locked to version 2.2.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 3
    - phpunit/phpunit is locked to version 4.8.36 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.36 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 4
    - phpoffice/phpexcel 1.8.2 requires ext-xmlwriter * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xmlwriter extension.
    - maatwebsite/excel 2.1.30 requires phpoffice/phpexcel ^1.8.1 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpexcel[1.8.2].
    - maatwebsite/excel is locked to version 2.1.30 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-xmlwriter --ignore-platform-req=ext-dom --ignore-platform-req=ext-dom --ignore-platform-req=ext-xmlwriter` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

Quando rodo o comando `php -m` aparece o seguinte:

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
Core
curl
date
fileinfo
filter
hash
json
libxml
mbstring
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Phar
Reflection
session
sodium
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

O comando `php --ini` retorna:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/tokenizer.ini
```

Answer (score -3):

O erro mostra que faltam duas extensões: `xmlwriter` e `dom`.
Sendo assim você deveria executar o seguinte comando e ver se resolve:

```sh
sudo apt-get install php-xmlwriter php-dom -y
```

Comment: na verdade a ext-xmlwriter e ext-dom são instaladas atravez da extensão php-xml